# HTTP header disappear while I do HTTP POST request with iPhone

Tags: php, objective-c, http, post, http-headers

i am new to Objective c and i stuck in a problem which **only appears when i do HTTP POST request**.

I do HTTP request with my iPhone and i expect the server returns me something like this in the header (this is the respond header from other server):

```
{
"Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 0;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "something";
Expires = "something";
Location = "/mylocation/10"; <--- this is what i want
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)";
"Set-Cookie" = "something";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.3";
}
```

When i do a successful posting ,it does the function that is want and returns an empty response with a header like this:

```
{
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, no-cache";
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 0;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "something";
Server = "Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)";
}
```

Even i add the headers like "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0", they will not be displayed in the respond header. 
 What should i do to get the correct header?

**Additional information**

I use ASIFormDataRequest to make request, here is the code that i set header:

```
{
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:something];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:@"something"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json,*/*;q=0.8"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
}
```

And this is how i get the respond headers:

```
{
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"%@", [request responseHeaders]);
}
```

Comment: Please, show your code where you make POST request and get response.

Comment: And provide code where you set headers.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, i edited the post and added some additional information, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Location headers will be sent only during the time of redirection. When we add a resource using PUT method the newly created URL will be added in the Location header and will be sent as part of the response. This also happens during 3xx redirection.